# Touchpad and Dual Display Not working Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, touchpad

I have HP probook laptop with below configuration

```
Processor: 11th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz × 8 
Grpahics: llvmpipe (LLVM 10.0.0, 256 bits
GNOME: 3.28.2
OS Type: 64 Bit
```

I am trying to get my Touchpad and Dual Monitor work on it. However, they aren't working. I tried installing NVIDIA Prime driver but it fails. Below is the result of my lpsci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9a14 (rev 01)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a03 (rev 01)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a0d (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a13 (rev 01)
00:0e.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation Device 9a0b
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device a0ed (rev 20)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device a0ef (rev 20)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device a0f0 (rev 20)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0e8 (rev 20)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a0e0 (rev 20)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0bd (rev 20)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0bf (rev 20)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device a0b0 (rev 20)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device a082 (rev 20)
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Device a0c8 (rev 20)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device a0a3 (rev 20)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device a0a4 (rev 20)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Device a809
```

I am new to Ubuntu and don't know what can be the problem. Can someone please guide me on what should be done to resolve it?

Comment: How does the Nvidia PRIME driver installation fail? Have you tried installing the Nvidia drivers from the built in Additional Drivers app? Can you update the question to add the output of `lsusb` and `libinput list-devices` for your touchpad? You may need to first run `sudo apt update && sudo apt install libinput-tools -y`.

Comment: I'll post it right away... Nvidia Prime installation works, but when i open Nvidia software it shows blank page

Comment: Also, it might be worth splitting this question in to two different questions - one for the Nvidia issue, and the other for the touchpad issue. That way, people who know about a specific topic are more likely to help you, and people finding the question by search engine can get an answer too once it’s solved for you.

Comment: For your Nvidia issue, have you tried the solution mentioned here? https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=342550

Answer (score 0):

it's probably because of synaptics package missing in installation.

follow [this](https://sangams.com.np/fix-ubuntu-18-4-touchpad-not-working-properly/) tutorials to check and install it.
after that install tweak tool to have better control on your environment